# "Thinking of " question for Comics readers

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

I am thinking of one of the following three comics characters

> > Hellboy
> >
> > Captain Marvel
> >
> > Spiderman

You can ask me one question starting with

> "Does the character you are thinking of ___?"
>
> I can then answer (truthfully :)
>
> YES
>
> NO
>
> Or just stay silent which means I am not sure or do not know

No sneaking in multiple questions by adding "and" "or" etc. Just one simple question.

Assume I have read these comics.

I do understand there could be several answers

Comment: Is the aim here to find one question that (on its own) identifies which character you're thinking of?

Comment: With the 3 possible responses given

Answer (score 5):

I could ask:

> ...appear in a Marvel comic?

Reasoning:

> Spiderman is indeed a Marvel comic, so yes.
>  Hellboy is a Dark Horse Comic, so no.
>  Captain Marvel is complicated because there are both DC and Marvel characters of that name and you don't know which one *I'm* thinking of, so not sure.

Comment: Good thinking. +1  My answer is a little different

Answer (score 4):

Does the character you are thinking of...

> ...appear in the upcoming film *Avengers: Endgame*?
>
>  - Hellboy - **No**. The Hellboy character belongs to a different company altogether.
>  - Captain Marvel - **Yes**. This has been confirmed and the character can be seen in recent trailers.
>  - Spider-Man - **Unsure**. It's been speculated that Spider-Man could have some role in the upcoming film, despite *(mumble mumble, no spoilers here)*. However, the character isn't included in the trailers, the film's poster or other advertising material as far as I can tell.

Comment: This site says Spiderman will be back: https://screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-spider-man-role-return/

Comment: @DEEM Ahh, there goes my theory!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying @Tahel's answer:

> Is the character a former human?

---

> YES: Spiderman's DNA was changed so he is no longer truly human.

---

> NO: Hellboy is and always has been a demon.

---

> UNSURE: Captain Marvel originally was a human who gained her powers via an alien device (still human), then they changed comics to make her mother Kree so she is half-human (never full human), and finally in the movie they made her merge with a Kree so her DNA changed (former human). Hard to answer with a simple yes or no!

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would ask:

> Does the character you are thinking of exist as a male human being?

explanation:

> **Hellboy**-He is a demon educated from infancy to do good deeds-If so in this case the answer would be **no**.

---

> **Captain Marvel**-She is a human being but a female - in this case the answer will **stay silent which means I am not sure or do not know**.

---

> **Spiderman**-He is a male human being and in this case the answer will be **yes**.

Comment: Hmm. Great. Getting closer. Good thinking

Comment: The answer to your question for Captain Marvel is pretty unambiguously "No" - why would the respondent have any doubt about how to answer?

Comment: There is no doubt that she is a human being but there is a doubt on the gender of human being,so the answer would be silence.

Comment: I don't understand. For sure there's doubt about _some_ human beings' gender (e.g., if you see them only from a distance), but why is there any in the case of Captain Marvel, a fictional character explicitly said to be female?

(Personally I'd say "no" for all of them, though, because none of them actually exists.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan WHAT??!  Spiderman, for sure, exists. Totally. I've seen him!